# How to append value to a specified column in csv with pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

[my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KetBA.png)

you can see for example the column world, there are some blank box, how can I replace it with new value, and then continue append new value to the world column. I tried many ways but I couldn't do it.

Comment: To update Excel workbooks from Python one option is [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better tell us what you tried, not just "many things".
Did you try [this](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-append-to-csv/)? You can copy all the values from the other columns which you don't need to change and only change the "world" column (a little work with indexes).

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can't write comments to the question yet, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Export the excel file as csv (comma-separated values) file and read the file using pandas. Say, you csv file name is `data.csv`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df
```

Output:

[image]

To replace the NaN values in the world column:

```
df['world'] = df['world'].replace(np.nan, 'some country')
```

To replace the NaN values in the whole dataframe:

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, 'some value')
```

To replace inplace i.e., no need to reassign:

```
df.replace(np.nan, 'some value', inplace=True)
```

To append some other values in dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[True, 'bob', 'canada', 'hi'], [False, 'marley', 'jamaica', np.nan]], 
                    columns=['status', 'user', 'world', 'cat'])
df = df.append(df2)
```

After all these operations, the dataframe may look like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you that helped, I just found out I could use df.loc[0,'world'] = 'somecountry' to replace put the value in the right location I wanted.